# Two same string in file but need replace the word in second string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have file which contain below string in file.

```
ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf';
```

With bash methods I want to replace second "undotbs01.dbf" to another name. When I did it with grep and sed it changes all undotbs01 words in file, to the new value. But I need only second undotbs (which located after "TO" word) to be changed.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mre] with actual code so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: `sed` and `grep` are external tools, not "Bash methods".

Comment: Are you actually trying to write an SQL parser? That has definitely been done before (though not in Bash). If you can supply the input and output names as strings, generating the SQL from that would be a lot simpler and more robust than trying to parse a language which might include line breaks between any two tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/undotbs01\.dbf/new_value/2' input_file
ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '/home/oracle/oradata/new_value';
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` back-references this is what I suggest:

```
$ cat in
ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf';
$ sed -e "s,\(.*/\).*\(dbf.*\),\1newname.\2," < in
ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '/home/oracle/oradata/newname.dbf';
```

This uses the greedyness of the first `.*` pattern (i.e. it wants to match as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting an `awk` script:

#### awk script:

```
awk '{sub(".*",str,$(NF-1));print}' FS="'" OFS="'" str="123"
```

#### results in:

```
awk '{sub(".*",str,$(NF-1));print}' FS="'" OFS="'" str="123" <<< $(echo "ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf';")
ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE '/home/oracle/oradata/undotbs01.dbf' TO '123';
```

#### instructions:

Put replacement string in `str="value"` or variable name $var `str="$var"`

#### Explanation

`FS="'"`   set `awk` field separator to `'`

`OFS="'"`  set `awk` output field separator to `'`

`sub(".*",str,$(NF-1))`   substitute/replace value of (last field - 1) with `str` value. The last field `$FN` is the termination `;`